# Boundary conditions for EM waves on an imperfect conductive surface separating two dielectrics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, waves, maxwell-equations

Let's say two semi-infinitely large dielectrics (dielectric permittivities are *ε<sub>1</sub>* and *ε<sub>2</sub>*, magnetic permeability are the same μ<sub>0</sub>) are separated by an infinitely thin imperfect conductive plane. An incident wave of *E<sub>i</sub>* propagates perpendicular to the plane, since the conductive plane is not perfect, currents will flow on the boundary.

If the conductive plane doesn't exist, we've already known the B.C. as following

*E<sub>i//</sub>+E<sub>r//</sub>=E<sub>t//</sub>*
*D<sub>i⊥</sub>+D<sub>r⊥</sub>=D<sub>t⊥</sub>*
*H<sub>i//</sub>-H<sub>r//</sub>=H<sub>t//</sub>*
*B<sub>i⊥</sub>-B<sub>r⊥</sub>=B<sub>t⊥</sub>*

How does the current on the imperfect conductive plane flow and whats the new boundary conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out by myself.

The surface must have some sort of current flowing to match the boundary conditions. Since the surface is infinitely thin, we could ommit the magnetic field on the surface.

Thus we have a system of three layers when considering the electric field, and two layers with free current flowing on the boundary when it comes to the magnetic field. The boundary conditions apply as follows:

(Using J<sub>f</sub> to refer to the current on the conducting surface and E<sub>c</sub> to refer to the electric field, and J<sub>f</sub>=σE<sub>c</sub>)

E<sub>i//</sub>+E<sub>r//</sub>=E<sub>c</sub>=E<sub>t//</sub>

H<sub>i//</sub>-H<sub>r//</sub>=H<sub>t//</sub>+J<sub>f</sub>

When σ=∞, the surface is a perfect conductor and by solving the two equations we can confirm there would be no E<sub>t//</sub> and H<sub>t//</sub>.